# VSTS will not show one of my product backlog item in the board

Tags: azure-devops

I am using VSTS with a Scrum template. This template has no customization, except the Backlog Items Board where I have the following columns:

- New
- Approved
- Being Worked
- Doing
- Done
- Blocked
- Committed
- Done

My problem is that I have a Product Backlog Item #143 that won't show up on the board and I can't explain why. It is visible in the backlog, but not in the board.

Here is the Product Backlog Item **#143** that is not visible in the board:
[image: Does not show up]
The Child items are only Tasks and Bugs. The parent is a Feature.

Here is another Product Backlog Item **#148** that shows up on the board:
[image: Shows up]
Here you can see the board, the item **#143** is not visible, but **#148** is:
[image]

I tried to change the status of **#143** from 'Approved' to 'New', back and forth but ; I also tried to remove it from the iteration and put it back but it did not help. Do you have any idea what to do?

Comment: What the state mapping for Doing and Done of Being Worked column? And you can also click **Create query** in Backlog Tab to check if the clauses and operations are correct as the issue met https://github.com/Microsoft/mail2bug/issues/61.

Comment: Thank you Martina, the problem was because I changed the setting to have the bugs handled with the requirements, and I had two bugs attached to #143. Removing "Parent" link between the requirement and the bugs fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you configured the setting "Working with Bugs". I can see that you have set this to "Bugs are managed with requirements.", because the bugs are appearing on the board.
With this setting bugs behave exactly like PBIs and the boards don't link nested work items on the same level. In those cases only the "deepest" work items show up on the board. Those are your bugs 210 and 212.

With the setting above you must not link work items on the same level (in this case PBI and Bug) with a parent/child link. If you want to associate Bugs with PBIs you have to use a "Related"-link or maybe "Predecessor".

Comment: You got it! I didn't pay attention to that... Initially the bugs were handled with tasks and we just changed this setting so that they are handled with the requirements. Thanks!